# Not able to see edges in web interface of ARANGODB

Tags: graph, arangodb

I have added edge doc as (name of edge is edge1)

```
{"_from":"test_doc2/2a","_id":"test_edge2/93615","_key":"93615","_rev":"_fcgKVwG--_","_to":"test_doc2/3a"},
{"_from":"test_doc2/3a","_id":"test_edge2/93616","_key":"93616","_rev":"_fcgKVwG--A","_to":"test_doc2/4a"}......
```

and vertex as(name of document is vertex1)

```
{"_id":"test_doc2/93490","_key":"93490","_rev":"_fcgIInG---","key":"1a","name":"abc"},
{"_id":"test_doc2/93491","_key":"93491","_rev":"_fcgIInG--_","key":"2a","name":"bcd"}......
```

and then making a graph in which EDGE is 'edge1' and in from and to both 'vertex1' is selected.

[image: graph shown on web interface]

When I want to see this in web interface nodes are visible but not the edges. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The document identifiers referenced in the `_from` and `_to` attributes of the edges do not match with the identifiers of your vertices.

For example, you reference `"test_doc2/2a"` but the actual value is `"test_doc2/93491"`. The document ID is the collection name, a forward slash and the `_key` value (note the underscore). The values of other attributes are irrelevant, including your `key` attribute.